# Recive 400 bad request when calling my webapi

Tags: c#, iis

Created a webapi, all goes well in postman, but when i created a front app in angular 7 and try to login got an error :Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Tried to disable cors for development in chrome, but still same error, configured webapi to allow all, still the same, changed web config to allow options for the preflight method, still the same.(Using owin)

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);


            WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);
            app.UseWebApi(configuration);
```

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your IIS is not supporting OPTION verb Calls
https://support.deskpro.com/en/kb/articles/configuring-http-verbs-on-windows-iis

Comment: Try and include the relevant context from links in your answer - see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)